# android volume up down event listen and send the broadcast

Tags: android, events, volume

I'm trying to make an application where the user can update the values of database on the volume up/down buttons and 2-3 activity can change the UI on volume up down as well. i want broadcast to be sent to all activity on volume up/down events, so dependent activity can change the UI and update the database as well.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Where is your code? What did you try so far? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 2):

You should create your receiver class
and register your receiver with these action:

```
<receiver android:name=".StreamVolumeReceiver">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION" /> 
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```